# Heater on bed stopped working on Fusion3 EDGE printer

Tags: heated-bed

I just received a Fusion3 EDGE printer and tried printing ABS with a 0.4 mm extruder at 260 °C and bed at 115 °C (the temperatures set by the demo print).  The bed started heading on the first print, then stopped heating after a few layers and hasn't heated since after repeated tries.  Does anyone know if the fault state is causing this or if a failed heater is causing the fault state?

I've been going through the document [Fusion3 EGDE-Troubleshooting: Heater Faults](https://www.fusion3design.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/EDGE-TROUBLESHOOTING-Heater-Faults-6.26.23.pdf).

Reset the heater fault and get the heater is heating too slowly.

I'm waiting for tech support's response before moving this to an answer, but this is the result so far.

I measured the voltages on the SRDD100 relay.  When the bed heater was turned on 24 V was across the input and the output passed 24 V to the heater (relay on).  When the bed heater changed to the fault condition, the input had 0 V and the output did not pass the 24 V to the heater (relay off).  Turning the power off on the 3D printer, unplugging the bed heater, and measuring the resistance of the bed heater showed an open circuit.

[image: Photo of the interface screen of a Fusion 3 Edge printer showing an error: 'Reset Heater Fault']

[image: Photo of the interface screen of a Fusion 3 Edge printer showing an error: Heter Fault 'Error; M25: Cannot pause print, because no file is being printed!']

[image: Photo of the interface screen of a Fusion 3 Edge printer showing an error: 'Error; M190: Can't turn heater 0 on while in fault state']

[image: Photo of the interface screen of a Fusion 3 Edge printer showing an error: Bed Heater Fault! 'Error; M140: Can't turn heater 0 on while in fault state']

[image: Photo of the interface screen of a Fusion 3 Edge printer showing an error: First Run Error! 'Error; M140: Can't turn heater 0 on while in fault state']

[image: Photo of the interface screen of a Fusion 3 Edge printer showing an error: 'Error; M190: Can't turn heater 0 on while in fault state']

[image: Photo of the build plate showing a 3D model being printed]

[image: Photo of the build plate where a 3D model has become detached]

Comment: Note: the ABS not adhering and touching the bed indicated that the bed was indeed at room temperature.

Comment: My first step is to go through this document just sent. https://www.fusion3design.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/EDGE-TROUBLESHOOTING-Heater-Faults-6.26.23.pdf

Comment: Appears to be open circuit for bed heater.

Comment: This should be followed up by a call to the vendor or the manufacturer. You wouldn't expect this for such an acclaimed high end commercial printer.

Comment: @Oscar I am working with the OEM now.  This was the easiest way to give them images.  If they don't post an answer here, I will post their answer.  I have requested the parts needed to change the bed heater element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I measured the voltages on the SRDD100 relay. When the bed heater was turned on 24 V was across the input and the output passed 24 V to the heater (relay on). When the bed heater changed to the fault condition, the input had 0 V and the output did not pass the 24 V to the heater (relay off). Turning the power off on the 3D printer, unplugging the bed heater, and measuring the resistance of the bed heater showed an open circuit. **The OEM also concluded that the bed heating element failed and is shipping a replacement**.

OEM comment:

> every machine that is built runs through at least 12 hours of printing high temperature materials before it is allowed to ship. Having it basically show up not functioning is. . really weird.

My response:

> This looks like it was on the tail of infant mortality for the heater exceeding the burnin time or a burnin escape.  It only lasted a few minutes into a print with bed at 110C.   Otherwise, it would be a defect caused in the process between burnin and arriving here.

The packaging showed no sign of mishandling and nothing on the unit showed signs of mishandling.  There was no sign of damage to the heater.  **The lack of response to this question here supports that this is a rare incident.**

The OEM has also requested the return of the failing heater element for analysis (shipping container included with replacement part).

Received new bed from OEM, installed bed, and printed successfully. First print after installing bed:

[image]

Below is normally a difficult print to not have strings between the stringers, but the Fusion3 Edge printed with no strings on the first attempt.

[image]

---

*When looking at SRDD100 application notes, I wondered why the 3D printer designer switched the positive supply voltage instead of the ground as in the application notes. But, thinking about this, the heater is attached to the grounded aluminum bed. If the designer switched the ground instead of the positive supply, a short to the bed could cause thermal runaway. Thus, the designer had safety in mind.*

Comment: Even if tested sometimes components do fail prematurely. Kudos for referring to this case being a rare incident and to the support of the manufacturer, this is handled as it should for a high end piece of machinery. Would love to test one! 

Comment: Please accept the answer after 48 hours!

Comment: @Oscar its working great.